# losing encoding of string when pushing to json in python

Tags: python, linux, utf-8

Im trying to run a a script in Python on a Linux server that runs a mysql query that results in a few Hebrew strings(made it one here to simplify) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env  python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()
import sys
import urllib
import base64
from MySQL import sql
print """Content-Type: text/html\n"""
s = sql()
s.run("SET NAMES utf8;")
query = "SELECT page FROM pages"
results = s.run(query)
s.close()
ans = {}
ans['count'] = 0
ans['items'] = []    
for res in results:
    page = result[0].encode('utf-8')
    print "====="+page+"======"
    ans['items'].append({
           'td0':page
    })
print ans
s.close()
```

this awkwardly prints

```
"Content-Type: text/html"

====/מפת-זרזיר/גריפאת/1/====
{'count': 0, 'items': [{ 'td0': '/\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa4\xd7\xaa-\xd7\x96\xd7\xa8\xd7\x96\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8/\xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xa4\xd7\x90\xd7\xaa/1/'}]}
```

why oh why does the page in the dictionary lose the encoding???
I have no idea why it happened. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not encode the data by hand. Use the `json` module instead, and leave the data as Unicode:

```
import json

for res in results:
    page = result[0]
    print "====={}======".format(page.encode('utf8')
    ans['items'].append({
        'td0':page
    })

print json.dumps(ans)
```

The `json` module will handle the encoding for you.

You are printing a python dictionary, not a JSON mapping, and Python uses string literal representations for the bytes in the string. This representation uses `\x..` escapes to represent any non-printable character. Since you are printing UTF-8 data directly, the data contains many bytes that are not printable, but the data is still there:

```
>>> print '/\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa4\xd7\xaa-\xd7\x96\xd7\xa8\xd7\x96\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8/\xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xa4\xd7\x90\xd7\xaa/1/'.decode('utf8')
/מפת-זרזיר/גריפאת/1/
```

If I take your example value and use the `json` module on the other hand produces valid JSON output:

```
>>> ans = {'count': 0, 'items': []}
>>> ans['items'].append('/\xd7\x9e\xd7\xa4\xd7\xaa-\xd7\x96\xd7\xa8\xd7\x96\xd7\x99\xd7\xa8/\xd7\x92\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99\xd7\xa4\xd7\x90\xd7\xaa/1/'.decode('utf8'))
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps(ans)
{"count": 0, "items": ["/\u05de\u05e4\u05ea-\u05d6\u05e8\u05d6\u05d9\u05e8/\u05d2\u05e8\u05d9\u05e4\u05d0\u05ea/1/"]}
```

JSON allows for `\u....` escape codes, and the module uses those to represent non-ASCII and non-printable characters. This is *normal*, a compliant JSON decoder will read this just fine.

Comment: Hi..I tried the dumps and removed the .encode('utf-8') for the page..still prints it as in the original post

Comment: @user1432779: If you get the exact same output as your original post you didn't reload your code correctly.

Comment: If you're returning JSON (for a RESTful/Hypermedia API) then you should be returning utf-8 encoded data in the first place. The json module does this correctly for you. You shouldn't expect to see the data as you do when you print it to the screen as a string.

Comment: Kudos!!!!! Worked just fine..you're right the json decoder does know how to handle it :-)

Answer (score 0):

This stems from creating a string with: `"=====" + page + "====="` and printing it and from the fact that printing a dictionary will use `repr(ans)` and that the representation may differ. You're not losing the encoding though.

**Edit**

As Martijn said, you can create a new string with the `json` module if in fact that is your purpose. If so, you shouldn't be printing the line before-hand otherwise some clients may be unable to parse the data (assuming you're making an API).

Comment: Hi..the print was for debug purposes